# paginate using php or js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this php code that fetches images from the database using the userid, then displays all the images in a list form. im trying to paginate the images, in a limit of 5 items per page. but the code is showing only the first page, without a link to the other pages. here's my php code

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';


        $Category = " ";
        $query = "SELECT Img_dir, Caption, Category FROM images WHERE Category = '". $_REQUEST['Category'] ."' AND user_id = '". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."' LIMIT 0,5";


        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $image = $row["Img_dir"];
            $Caption= $row["Caption"];
            $Category = $row["Category"];
                echo "<dl>";

                echo "<dd>$Category &nbsp&nbsp <img src='base64_encode($image)' />&nbsp&nbsp $Caption<dd>";

                echo "</dl>";
                }
        //number of total pages available
        $results_per_page = 10;

        $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results / $results_per_page);
        echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
        for($r=1;$r<=$number_of_pages;$r++)
        {
            ?><a href="dashboard.php?page=<?php echo $r;?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $r." "; ?></a><?php 
        }
```

?>

Comment: your syntax is all over the place `?><a href="dashboard.php?page=<?php echo $r;?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $r." "; ?></a><?php ` should be `echo '<a href="dashboard.php?page='.$r.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.$r.'</a>';`

Comment: Your sql query has a hard coded limit of 0,5 which means it always return 5 records. In order for pagination to work you would have to call your php code again n again for very page. Then you will write the query that will return rows based on selected pageset.

Comment: @tim if you want to be pedantic about it, it could actually be `printf('<a href="dashboard.php?page=%d" style="text-decoration:none">%d</a>', $r, $r);` but really, the answer is a proper templating engine.

Comment: You will need one additional query in addition to @NawedKhan observation for your limit. Your additional query will need no limit because it will be used for getting the total number of results. Using one query you will always get a total number of results that matches your limit.

Comment: @NawedKhan if i remove the LIMIT it displays the paginations at the bottom but does not adhere to 10 results per page

Comment: As @imvain2 mentioned it is not as simple as what you have. You will need atleast 2 queries, one for count and one for limit. It is more involved. Read this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm  and do a little more research on pagination with php and mysql.